# Imperfect symmetries (in sculpt mode)

Tags: sculpting

When in Sculpt Mode, I usually keep the X symmetry locked, which is useful. But isn't it also a bit inconsistent? now and then, while sculpting, i notice that the symmetry is not always perfect. is this normal? or am i doing something wrong (such as hittin without knowing some shortcut or something)?

Comment: What is inconsistent? Why isn't it "always perfect"? Can you show some images of the example mesh? Note that symmetry of the sculpting mode depends on the transforms of the object which are better to have applied (Object mode > Ctrl+A)

Comment: Was the mesh truly symmetric to start with? Small variations will prevent the symmetry option applying to opposing vertices. In the dyntopo panel, there is a button to symmetrize the mesh over a chosen axis.

Comment: sorry guys i cant find a good example. was sculpting some teeth and id swear they morphed asymetrically. maybe it was indeed something related to unapplied transforms. cheers

Comment: I can attest to this as well. Its very slight, so hard to notice until your 10 hours into your sculpt. Don't know what tool or action causes it. My usual Band-Aid has been to regenerate symmetry along X, but that messes with details around the symmetry line.

Answer (score 1):

There are absolutely inconsistencies, I believe it's a result of smoothing but may be wrong. Mesh is absolutely perfect before using sculpt mode (I checked), from the side in this image you can see that the mesh no longer aligns correctly. This was using X symmetry, the default brush (+ autosmooth) + smooth / autosmooth. 
[image]